# How to play audio in background

Tags: android, android-videoview

I use VideoView to play audio from URL.
My code is as below:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse(url[i]);
vv.setVideoURI(video);
vv.setMediaController(mediaController);
vv.start();
```

I want to play audio in background.
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanna play the audio in the background, whats the need to do it with `VideoView`.
Just use the `MediaPlayer` for this.

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Is it possible to use VideoView?

Comment: but you wanna play it in background, right??
And Video view is a view, ie. some thing to be used when you need to show it on the screen.

Comment: yes you can use the video view too, and make it disappear but continue to run the media content in it. But whats the need of that.

Comment: Either modify your question and tell exactly what do you want and then any one can give you a clear answer meeting your requirment

Comment: Because it may play audio or video. If it play video, I want to only play audio in background. If it is impossible, I will split it to two part activity.

Comment: May more detail of "make it disappear but continue to run the media content in it"?

Comment: yes, add a video view to your layout xml and give its height width a very minimum limit or use "videoView.setVisibility(View.Invisible)", so that it wont appear in the view at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7715/discussion-between-akkilis-and-brian)

Comment: how can i hide this media player in background and when ever i need how to call them in forground?

Comment: @AndroidOptimist : for that you may run it in a service and can have an activity that displays just the UI of a media player (seek bar and all that stuff). You can display a notification in the notification bar , on clicking it your activity will be opened but media player will be running in a service.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
    this,
    Uri.parse("http://sirisak.comule.com/markmix96west.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Is it possible to use VideoView?

Comment: You don't need a view at all for the mediaPlayer because in this case we are not using the "MediaControllers", so again in this case we are merely streaming "the audio from a server to our application". For video a more advanced approach should be taken so as to not disregard the users ability to control the activity without closing out the application.  If a you are using an additional sdk for displaying video you should consult with the Instructions of that sdk before using any alternative methods.